# Simple Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, directory, delete-file

An argument example:

```
../path/cse/lab3/remove
```

Right now, it's printing out all the directory and files in 'lab3'.
I want it to print out all the files in 'remove'.
I'm not sure how to do that. I want to use a for loop.

Code:

```
if test -d $1    #check if argument is a directory.
then

    for fileName in *
    do  
        echo "what is this::: $fileName"

    done

fi
```

Also how do I print out all the files as strings to look something like this:

```
remove/test.out
remove/test2.out
```

Comment: See the [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) command for the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
for fileName in $1/*
```

...is probably what you mean.